# Limit for unicode characters in iText

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to add an Ohm symbol to my PDF as `\u2126`. But its doesn't show up on the PDF. Is there a special font or encoding type I need to set?

The symbol needed is: Ω

Comment: Like this `new Phrase("Ohm Symbol \u2126", new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10))`

Comment: For using Unicode symbols or characters, you need to create a font with BaseFont.EMBEDDED and BaseFont.IDENTITY_H.